# Linq: How to query items from a collection until the sum reaches a certain value

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following object:

```
public class Product {
   string Name {get;} 
   int Quantity {get;}
}
```

using Linq, how would I query a `List<Product>` until I got a sum `>=` a given quantity? In other words, if my list looked like

```
Name     Quantity
-----------------
prod1       5
prod2       6
prod7       7
```

I want to query the List and pull instances until I get a Sum `>=8`.  In this case I'd get the first two items in the List. If I wanted sum `>= 12`, I'd get all three.

I know I can write a loop to do this for me, but I was fantasizing that there was some slick one-liner using Linq to achieve the same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a quick 2 liner.

```
var sum = 0;
var query = col.Where(x => { var temp = sum; sum += x.Quantity; return temp < 500; });
```

Replace 500 with the constant or variable of your choosing.

**EDIT**

Here is mquander's more efficient solution

```
var sum = 0;
var query = col.TakeWhile(x => { var temp = sum; sum += x.Quantity; return temp < 500; });
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to do the exact same thing except instead of .Where(), to use .TakeWhile(), and check whether the sum at the start is greater than 500, not at the end (else you'll take one too few elements.) Then the iteration would cease when the 500 barrier is broken.

Comment: TakeWhile() is much better. Good one @mquander!

Comment: Just a side-note: This isn't possible with "LINQ to SQL":
`A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

Comment: @Legends use `AsEnumerable()` before `TakeWhile` or `Where` for this error

Answer (score 1):

You just create a variable to hold the sum, then add to it as each item in the list is tested with the `where` clause:

```
int sum = 0;
from product in list where (sum += product.Quantity) < 8 select product
```

Comment: Interestingly, the more I use Linq, the more I find myself leaning toward the extension method syntax, except in cases where I'm querying the source in a very sql-ish fashion.  I wonder if that's a common pattern of linq usage?

Comment: Possibly - it's still early days for me.

Comment: That pattern of usage is what I've experienced... There's little point to writing that from and select clause if you just want to filter.  I revert back to the query comprehension syntax to use "let" clauses though.