# Using LINQ to pull collection until aggregate condition met

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate

At a high level, I need a query that can pull a subset of records based on the sum of a column, just like [Linq: How to query items from a collection until the sum reaches a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652383/linq-how-to-query-items-from-a-collection-until-the-sum-reaches-a-certain-value).

However, the key difference is that he's already got his records in an object, and I don't and can't. My table can have millions of records. If I build my query the way he did, I get this error:

```
"A lambda expression with a statement body 
 cannot be converted to an expression tree"
```

Which makes sense after researching it, LINQ can't turn the answer in the above referenced question into valid SQL.

I'm going to make a hypothetical table that represents my situation.

```
    Order Id | Cookie Name      | Qty
       1         Sugar             5
       2         Snickerdoodle     4
       3         Chocolate chip    8
       4         Snickerdoodle     10
       5         Snickerdoodle     5
```

Given this sample, I need to write a query that grabs the first `X` orders of `Snickerdoodle` until the summed Qty exceedes an input from the parameter (i.e. If the user chooses 13, it would return records 2 & 4 ).

I'm using Nhibernate.Linq, because I'm more comfortable in LINQ. I'm completely open to ICreate if the need arises.

As a side note, I'm interested in this as a concept as well as a direct problem. Even though I need a Sum, there has to be a way to do something akin to a takewhile that executes until a condition is met.

Comment: I think because he's also filtering for "Snickerdoodle".

Comment: I would suggest writing the sql, and than figuring out the LINQ expression.

Comment: It's probably quite complicated to represent that query in SQL, which means it's probably even worse (if possible at all) to do the query with NH. Jace is right; go for SQL first. You don't even have to convert it, NH supports mapping entities from SQL.

Comment: `If the user chooses 15 It would return records 2 & 4` Is this correct? Wouldn't their combined quantity be 14 rather than 15? I would think it would return `1 & 4` and `4 & 5`. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes I was filtering by snickerdoodle. I did make one mistake Ryan, so I changed the nunmber to better demonstrate. It would return 2 & 4 if the input was 13, at 15 it would return 2, 4 & 5. I'm on SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

pragmatic approach

```
int needed = ...;
int actual = 0;
int page = 0;
const int pagesize = 20;   // set to some sensible value, eg. the pagesize of the grid shown to the user
var results = new List<CookieOrder>();

while (actual < needed)
{
    var partialResults = session.Query<CookieOrder>()
        .Where(c => c.Name == "Snickerdoodle")
        .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
        .Skip(page * pagesize)
        .Take(pagesize)
        .ToList();

    for(int i = 0; i < partialResults.Length && actual < needed; i++)
    {
        results.Add(partialResults[i]);
        actual = partialResults[i].Quantity;
    }
    page++;
}

return results;
```

Comment: Great function, Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, it falls victim to the same one: scale. Doing a Take large enough to ensure I meet the "needed" parameter just pulls too many records.

Comment: i forgot the skip. it should consist of many small takes which add up.

Comment: This would technically get me the dataset i want, though I would certainly have to hit the database a few thousand times.

Comment: you could increase the take size then